# Redirect if first URL segment is not "admin"

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have recently changed the URL structure of a large site from:
/area/category/sub-category/business to /area/business.

I'm wanting to set up a redirect rule in my .htaccess so that people are directed onto the correct business.

The rewrite rule I have been playing around with works fine on the front-end of the site. When logging into the admin area to update a business, for example with the URL of: /admin/business/id/edit, I am redirected to /admin/edit

```
RewriteBase /
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /$1/$4
```

I feel that the first segment needs to be checked to make sure it does not equal "admin", but I am unsure of how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to redirect only `/area/` URL then you should specify it in a rule directly. And `/admin` URL won't be affected.

```
RewriteBase /
RedirectMatch 301 ^/area/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /$1/$4
```

Marked solution:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(?!admin/)(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /$1/$3.
```

Comment: The /area/ segment can be a list of different areas (Currently 5, but can potentially be limitless). Is it possible to say this segment can match anything, other than the word admin?

Comment: Try RedirectMatch 301 ^/(?!admin)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /$1/$4

Comment: That didn't quite work but was able to figure it out. I ended up with: RedirectMatch 301 ^/(?!admin/)(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /$1/$3.

thank you both for your help!